# Setup an interval schedule with exclusion

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm setting up a job in Quartz.NET that will be running fairly indiscriminately. The job will fire ever `X` number of minutes. It simply checks a directory and processes a file if it's present.

My issue that I'm having trouble determining in the API is how to exclude a block of time.

For example at the moment I'm trying to figure out how to disable the job for the first 15 minutes of every hour and then run at 5-minute intervals.

With all that said...

I have the job currently up and running and set to fire every five minutes, but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to add the exclusion to prevent the job from running the first 15 minutes of every hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
0 20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * ? *
```

EDIT: Per Jared's comment, this produces the same schedule:

```
0 20/5 * * * ? *
```

You can test it here:http://jayvilalta.com/quartznet/cronexpression

Comment: The only change that I see needing to be made is the `20,25...` can instead be written as... `20/5` nice added bonus of the expression tester!

Comment: It's good to know, I thought there was probably an easier way of doing it. Edited the answer to include yours.